# How to add reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll while copying an asp.net app from dev server to test server

Tags: asp.net, dll, reference, deploying

I am referencing Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll in my asp.net web application at development server.
No i need to move this app from development server to testing server.
I can't see the dll in the bin folder of the app as it is pointing to GAC.
How should i reference the above specified dll in testing server?
Do we need to do anything with web.config?
Please advice.

Thanks,
Ram

Comment: Don't.  Word is not intended for (and I think not licensed for) use in a server environment.  If you decide to do it anyhow, you will have to install a (licensed) copy of Word on each server (which will cause appropriate GAC registration).

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio uses different sets of the PIAs on the development computer. These different sets of assemblies are in the following locations:

A folder in the program files directory.

These copies of the assemblies are used when you write code and build projects. Visual Studio installs these assemblies automatically.

The global assembly cache.

These copies of the assemblies are used during some development tasks, such as when you run or debug projects that target the .NET Framework 3.5. Visual Studio does not install and register these assemblies; you must do this yourself.

[Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57.aspx#separateassemblies)

If not found DLL you have to download from internet....